# I try make a property bind on radio button but get this error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I need to leave the radio button selected according to a variable that I have, use the value of the control.

I try do this property bind but get error:

```
 private turnoId = 0;
      private nivelId = 2;
```

and html:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Turnos</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
 <label  class="radio-inline col-sm-3" *ngFor="let turno of turnos">
<input  #vl [checked]="vl.value == turnoId" type="radio" name="radioTurno" [value]="turno.id" (change)="onSelectionChangeTurno(turno)"> {{ turno.descricao }}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="line"></div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Nível de Acesso</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <label class="radio-inline col-sm-3" *ngFor="let nivelAcesso of nivelAcessoList" >
                                            <input  #vl2 [checked]="vl2.value == nivelId" type="radio" name="radioNivelAcesso" [value]="nivelAcesso.id" (change)="onSelectionChangeNivelAcesso(nivelAcesso)"> {{ nivelAcesso.ds_nivel_acesso }}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: I try it but not work too:                                                                                         <input  [ngModel]="{checked: nivelId == nivelAcesso.id}" type="radio" name="radioNivelAcesso" [value]="nivelAcesso.id" (change)="onSelectionChangeNivelAcesso(nivelAcesso)"> {{ nivelAcesso.ds_nivel_acesso }}

Answer (score 0):

correct bind:

```
[checked]="nivelAcesso.id == nivelId"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <label class="radio-inline col-sm-3" *ngFor="let nivelAcesso of nivelAcessoList" >              <input  #vl2 
      [checked]="checkId(v12.value,turnoId)" type="radio" name="radioNivelAcesso" 
  [value]="nivelAcesso.id" (change)="onSelectionChangeNivelAcesso(nivelAcesso)"> {{ nivelAcesso.ds_nivel_acesso }}  </label>
```

And add this method inside your component:

```
checkId(a?:number,b?:number){
      if(a==b){
   return true;
      }
       return false;

     }
```